# When setting up a dev environment using nginx, fastcgi, and php, I am getting "Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request)" from php server

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I am setting up a development environment that uses nginx and forwards requests to a command line php server using fastcgi. When I send requests to the php server directly, it handles them correctly. The nginx server can properly handle requests for non-php files. However, when I send a php request through nginx, the php server is hit, but returns with "Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request)".

Apologies for attaching all of my configuration files, but I'm not sure where to start. All files are located in `$PROJECT_PATH/dev-config/`.

Here are the relevant parts of my nginx config.

```
http {
    ...

    server {
        root .;
        listen       8123;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            index  index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        fastcgi_params;  # this file is the default
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the script that gets run to (re-)start nginx and php:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJECT_PATH="$(dirname $0)/../"

nginx -s stop || true
nginx -c dev-config/nginx.conf -p $PROJECT_PATH

php -c php-dev.ini -t $PROJECT_PATH -S 127.0.0.1:9123
```

The file I am sending is test.php:

```
<? echo 'YAY!' ?>
```

Inside of my nginx error logs, I get messages like this:

```
2017/10/27 08:12:56 [error] 68934#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9123", host: "localhost:8123"
```

Simultaneously, php is sending messages like this:

```
[Fri Oct 27 08:12:56 2017] 127.0.0.1:52470 Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request)
```

This shows that the request is handled by nginx and sent onward to the php server. But the request is somehow incorrect.

1. What can I do to send properly formed requests?
2. Or, if that's impossible to tell right now, what can I do to get more info from php as to what request, exactly, it is getting?

To be clear, this is meant to be run in a dev environment on a laptop with no configuration changes for each user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem that I was having was that the commandline php server does not have fastcgi running with it. Since the commandline server is already a server, I don't need fastcgi at all. Instead, I can `proxy_pass` to it.

I changed the php location block to this and it worked:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9123;
}
```